# What type of voltage control should I use for a battery power bank (using old alk. AA, C, D...) to provide low voltage for a light?

Tags: voltage, control

My collection of partially spent batteries has increased, and I would like to use a battery holder to build a power bank/supply which will provide power for a low voltage light (to be attached to my garage bicycle pump), but am confused as to what kind of voltage control I should best use to adjust the voltage.

From what I read on this site, It seems a potentiometer is not what it best, and that instead I need some sort of simple (cheap) voltage divider. The alkaline batteries would range in voltage from 1v. to 12v (23a: doorbell type), and the light would likely be  3v.

I have used a  DC motor speed PWM to control the speed on a 12V DC motor, but I do not know if that is what I should use on this project.

I am  aware that both the battery voltage and  discharge rate would vary, but unless there is a real problem with that then I rather face that then see these batteries go to waste when they still have some some left in them.

So if someone can tell me the name of what I am looking for I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The higher-voltage batteries should go through a buck converter down to 3v.

The lower-voltage (1.5v) cells can utilize a Joule thief circuit to run a 3v LED directly.

Comment: Thanks, you mean like <a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/1X-Adjustable-Buck-Voltage-Regulator-Power-LM2596-Module-DC-DC-3-3V-5V-9V-12V-3A/122619678017?hash=item1c8cb3cd41:g:RmUAAOSw1cNaAq42 ">this   </a>  And why would not that work for the   the lower voltage  bats if I ran them in series? You mean there is no basic voltage control that will do both?

Comment: You could use multiple cells in series (a battery is composed of multiple cells, only the 9v/12v are "batteries", fwiw), but the performance will be restricted by the most-dead cell.  A Joule-thief is a well-known circuit that can be built very simply and will extract all the remaining power out of a cell.  There's no reason the buck converter and joule thief outputs couldn't connect to the same LED.

Comment: The  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief">Joule thief - Wikipedia</a> is very interesting.  "Clive originally named the circuit "Vampire Torch", because it sucked the last remnants of life from a battery."

Comment: I originally though I would just stack cells together and control the voltage, but I <a href="https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/whats-the-purpose-of-a-joule-thief.112539/ ">read </a>, Stacking a pile of worn out cells to get the original voltage won't work - the cells will all have varying amounts of internal resistance, the one with the highest resistance will be reverse 'charged' - that is a reverse voltage will be impressed across its terminals by other more lively cells. That can cancel out the voltage supplied by some other cells that are actually doing something.

Comment: I am not sure how to make this work for  multiple cells, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. There is an instructable here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Joule-Thief/